# How to show php result in Json encode

Tags: php, json, encode

I trying to check client ip is using proxy or not with this code

```
<?php

$proxy_ports = array(80,81,8080,443,1080,6588,3128);
    foreach($proxy_ports as $test_port) {
        if(@fsockopen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $test_port, $errno, $errstr, 5)) {
            exit("vpn Connect");
        }
    }
?>
```

It's working for me but i want to get php result in Json encode format
like {"vpn" :"ok"}
I mean when client ip connect with proxy then this code show a result  **vpn connect**
I want the result in Json encode format like **{"vpn" :"ok"}**

Please someone help me how can I do this.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Upvoted cool username! Replace the exit line with `echo json_encode(["vpn" => "ok"]);` and tell us if it work.

Comment: having a port open is not an indication the client is going through a vpn or a http proxy

Comment: It's working  Thank you so much  but you say { having a port open is not an indication the client is going through a vpn or a http proxy}  can you tell me which the best way detect proxy or vpn plz

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$proxy_ports = array(80,81,8080,443,1080,6588,3128);
$payload = ['vpn', 'ko'];
foreach($proxy_ports as $test_port) {
    if(@fsockopen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $test_port, $errno, $errstr, 5)) {
        $payload['vpn'] = 'ok';
        break;
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($payload);
```

`header('Content-Type: application/json');` will tell to your browser what the type of the returned content.

`json_encode` will transform your variable in json valid string.